# Delete a line form a text file

Tags: c#, .net

I need to delete a line from a text file. The problem is, when I try to delete a line, I have to press BtnStergeMedicam twice to delete. I don't know why I have to press it twice.

```
private void BtnStergeMedicam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    string line_to_delete = ListAfisMedicam.SelectedItem.ToString();//I take the line
    //to delete from ListAfisMedicam
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\MyTest.txt"))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\MyTest2.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
                    continue;
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
             writer.Close();
        }
         reader.Close();
    }
    System.IO.File.Copy(@"D:\MyTest2.txt", @"D:\MyTest.txt",true);
    ListAfisMedicam.Items.Clear();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\MyTest.txt");
    foreach (string linie in lines)
    {
        ListAfisMedicam.Items.Add(linie);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you have to click it twice? You click an item in your listbox, click it, then click the same item again and it works? And does it put it in your MyTest2 and just doesn't copy over?

 Also, general coding practices: this isn't java or C++, you can use == to compare string operators, and using () automatically closes and disposes streams, so remove your read and writer close statements (that's what using actually does)

Comment: Probably first time `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\MyTest2.txt");` return 0 lines. Try to debug the code.

Comment: FYI you don't need to `Close` the streams since you have them in `using` statements.

Comment: have you even used the debugger to step through the code..

Comment: @erikscandola that will only populate the listbox, that won't remove lines from the MyTest file. But with that said, it's also possible that whatever is currently populating the list box does not have the identical lines as in MyTest2.

Comment: I click an item in my listbox, then when I press the button for delete, doesn't do enything, after I press second time the button for delete, It delete

Comment: @ConstantinMihaila and what's populating the listbox initially?

Comment: The list is populating with lines like this 
ID - 01, Nume - Nurofen, Lot - 0123, Categorie - Capsula, Producator - Dona, Cantitate - 300, DataIntrare - 13-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, DataFabricarii - 01-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, DataExpirarii - 31-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, PretVanzare - 2;

Comment: Not sure, but my gut is telling me you have a caching issue of some sort going on, and the second click is actually copying the output from the first runthrough.  Keep a close eye on the timestamps of your files as you run your test.

Comment: are your button events being added by double clicking the button and or double clicking the OnClick in the event tab for that control..? or are you adding the button click events in a delegate somewhere in the Initialize etc.. try cleaning the solution and rebuilding it ..

Comment: Put a break point on the first line, and see if it actually gets in there the first time.

Comment: @MethodMan , I added button events by double clicking the button in FormDesigne

Comment: I read from MyTest.txt and when find the line what is like line I selected in listbox, I don't read it, and continue to read.After finish to read all lines, i save what i readed in MyTest2.txt, after that i copy MyTest2.txt into MyTest.txt

Comment: You need to step through the code and see what's happening - you especially need to check if execution is entering the BtnStergeMedicam_Click method at all when you first press the button.  If you aren't sure how to do that then this should get you going: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/

Comment: Thanks @tom_redox . It's first time when i use breakpoint. I put one at `System.IO.File.Copy(@"D:\MyTest2.txt", @"D:\MyTest.txt", true);` and it's seems till there only copy from MyTest.txt to MyTest2.txt. Copy and the line what I selected to be deleted

Comment: Once you're in debug mode stick a break point on near the start of the method and then you can press F11 to advance execution a line at a time and see what's happening in more detail. If you hit the breakpoint after pressing the button the first time then the issue is in the code you posted, if not, then the issue is somewhere else. That will probably get you to the solution, but if not once you've found exactly where the issue is happnening post a more specific question or edit the existing one. .

Comment: I put a breakpoint at `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\MyTest.txt"));` and it's seems line_to_delete have same text line ListAfisMedicam.SelectedItems

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  `ListAfisMedicam.SelectedItem.ToString()` return me `\nID - 01, Nume - Nurofen, Lot - 0123, Categorie - Capsula, Producator - Dona, Cantitate - 300, DataIntrare - 13-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, DataFabricarii - 01-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, DataExpirarii - 31-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM, PretVanzare - 2;` and when It read each line and compare, It read like upper but w/o `\n`
When I try second time( press the BtnStergeMedicam second time) `ListAfisMedicam.SelectedItem.ToString()` return `ID - 01, Nume -Nurofen ...`

Edit: Fix the problem. Thank you @tom_redox. The problem where somewhere else. When I populate list box I punt an `\n` and this was the problem. From now I will start use breakpoint everytime when I will got any problem

Comment: Well done Constantin, those skills will serve you well in the future